# Parsing and sorting nested information in a .json file

Tags: c#, json

I have a .json file that has values formatted like this:

```
main info :{  
  secondary info:{
    tertiary info:{
      details:[
        1,
        2,
        3]
  }
 }
}
```

I'd like to be able to parse this and get an array of just details so that I can pass that specific information into another function. So basically I want to sort through all of the information in the .json file and be able to just pull out the info from 'details'. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

your json is not valid , but when you have something like this

```
{
  "main info": {
    "secondary info": {
      "tertiary info": {
        "details": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can get details array using this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

int[] details=JObject.Parse(json)["main info"]["secondary info"]["tertiary info"]["details"].ToObject<int[]>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Is this using the Json.NET resource or something different?

Comment: @Maddy Yes,  I am  using Newtonsoft.Json; but if you want to use microsoft json and will be about the same.